# changing file descriptor limit rabbitmq does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I'm trying to change the file descriptor limit for a RabbitMQ server (hosted on AWS).

According to the relevant section of their manual, it ought to work like this:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#kernel-resource-limits

But when I check the status on the node itself, it does not seem to have changed anything.

Concretely, I executed

> systemctl status rabbitmq-server

This shows me the config file is located at

> /lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service

As per the instructions on the website, I changed

> /etc/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.d/limits.conf

to include

> [Service]
>   LimitNOFILE=300000

When checking the limit

> sudo rabbitmqctl status

I don't see any change

> {file_descriptors,
>        [{total_limit,924},
>         {total_used,751},
>         {sockets_limit,829},
>         {sockets_used,749}]},

So, what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify a systemd setting, you must run `systemctl daemon-reload` and then `systemctl restart rabbitmq-server`. We don't have that in the docs because we try not to document *everything*, but maybe I should add that to the docs.

Then, a reliable way to check the limit is to run

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'os:cmd("ulimit -n").'
"131072\n"
```

Comment: Oddly enough, the rabbit server reverted back to 830 all by itself.
Is that normal?
I saw (in the mgmt console) that it was set to my chosen limit. But the day afterwards it went back to 830.

Comment: What is the output of `rabbitmqctl eval 'os:cmd("ulimit -n").'` when the management console shows 830?

Comment: The output is "1024\n"

Comment: Hmm that means that `systemd` lowered the limit behind your back somehow. I would confirm that, for your installation, the custom limit file `/etc/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.d/limits.conf` is actually being used. RabbitMQ can't lower system limits, of course, since it doesn't have permission to do so (only `root` can).

Comment: And how do I check this?

Comment: Read your system manuals, or the `systemd` documentation. On my Arch Linux workstation, `man systemd.unit` shows the expected file locations and names.